# X select Y calculation on TI-83+ calculator

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, calculator

I've searched everywhere for a shortcut for this calculation on TI calculator, but can't find anything. X select Y, the formula is:

$$\frac{x!}{y!*(x-y)!}$$

Studying for test that has problems that require me to do this calculation a bunch of times, and it takes forever doing it manually.

Comment: This isn't really the site to ask for calculator support (I don't think). Anyway, there should be a button for probability, probably PRB and you're looking for the combination button. It might be nCr. Take a look at [this](http://www.statisticshowto.com/ti-83-permutation-combination-easy-steps/). Seems related.

Comment: nCr does the trick, thanks! They have a calculator tag for questions, i think it's ok to ask as long as you do a little research first, Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @Max The help center suggests that "Software that mathematicians use (except *Mathematica*)" is on-topic, and I don't see a difference between MATLAB and the TI-83+ beyond how the first is more powerful. And we do have a (calculator) tag...

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks. I'm well aware of what the help center says, but I've never actually seen a software or calculator question be well received. They seem to be far and few between. Anyway, I didn't down vote or close vote, in case anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 0):

The Best you can do:
(Example)

$$^{10}C_4=\frac{10!}{4!.6!}=\frac{10.9.8.7.6!}{4!.6!}=\frac{10*9*8*7}{4!}$$

Beyond this, only your speed can help you.

Comment: Thanks for response, for ti-83 it was x nCr y.